# Bloch unbounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this example of a unbounded Bloch function, defined on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.
$f(z) = \mathrm{arctanh}\,z$ is analytic with $|f(z)| \to +\infty$ as $z\to 1$. Since $f'(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^2}$, it satisfies $(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)| \leqslant 1$.

But I don't understand why the fuction is analytic? and why is true that $(1-|z|^2)|f'(z)| \leqslant 1$?

Comment: “Analytic in $\Bbb D$” is equivalent to “complex differentiable at every point $z \in \Bbb D$.” You already determined the derivative ...

Comment: note that Bloch functions cannot grow faster than logarithmic at the boundary ($|f(z)| \le -C\log (1-|z|)$ for some $C>0$ depending on $f(0)$ and the Bloch semi-norm of $f$), so even the unbounded ones are not that unbounded so to speak